# Binding Validation in UWP

Tags: wpf, win-universal-app

I know about Binding validation in WPF, but it seems that there is not those rules in UWP, for example UWP doesn't have `ValidateOnException` in binding Tag, Is it right? validation doesn't exist in UWP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, as far as I could gather, is **NO**. There is not an implemented validation system like in other XAML-based frameworks.

Jerry Nixon has a [tutorial](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2014/07/lets-code-handling-validation-in-your.html) and [example](http://xaml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Blog/201406-Validation/App10/Common/ModelBase.cs) about how to create your own validation control in order to implement validations similar to those in WPF.

The tutorial was created for Universal applications and the whole idea behind it is to create a wrapper control over the actual control you want to validate on and make all proper validations there using it as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

While this **may** not work right out of the box, I highly advise you to take a look at it (and try to spend some time with it, specially the actual github code).